# Send variables to JavaScript through nodejs express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been doing nodejs for a day now and I am trying to send a variable from my nodejs express server to a javascript file. I currently have the code;

```
res.send(String(playerLives));
```

player lives being an integer (already ran into the problem of sending an integer)

I'm just wondering how I reference/access playerLives within my javascript file?

I have it working in reverse direction (javascript to nodejs express) with the following code within nodejs express

```
req.query.varibalename
```

but how do I do the same within my javascript file?

Comment: Do you want to make a bridge with the same variable between node.js and javascript (front-end)? If is this, this is not possible. It's able to send values from the sides, not share the same variable.

Comment: You don't send a "variable" to "JavaScript" (not "java script"). Instead, you send (or respond with) some **data** to the **browser**, where it is most likely picked up by the handler for the HTTP request that initiated the  whole process, a sequence of events which is integral to the basic architecture of all web applications, and is described in detail in dozens or hundreds of tutorials. The details are going to be dependent on the client-side architecture and framework; your framework docs should help here.

Comment: @LucasCosta I just wish to pass any value, not neccesarily share the same vairbiable. I just dont understand how to access the value once sent via res.send (or if that is even that right command)

Comment: You can edit your question for meaning what you want. It's means what I and @torazaburo we say.

Comment: How are you making the request to get the value? Can you post some of that code? From there we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

For access data send to view from node.js, you can use [res.json](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html), [res.send](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html), [res.render](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html), etc.

Jquery function on view:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/test',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // show Hello world
    }
});
```

Express route:

```
app.get('/test', function(req,res) {
    var hello = "Hello world";
    res.send(hello);
});
```

Comment: I am getting a response as 'undefined' which is much better than nothing but any ideas why its not printing hello world in the console?